# Using cookies with REST::Client

Tags: perl, api, rest, http-headers

I'm trying to get REST::Client to use cookies in its requests. SO, I set it up like this:

```
my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new( file => "lwp_cookies.dat", autosave => 1 );
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( cookie_jar => $cookie_jar );
my $client = REST::Client->new({ useragent => $ua, host => $BASE_API_URL });
```

But when I do my `$client->GET()` and `$client->PUT` calls, there are no cookies headers passed around, and no cookies file is created on disk. I also tried add  `keep_alive => 1` option for LWP::UserAgent->new(), but my Connection headers are still `Connection: TE, close`.

I'm checking the requests with Fiddler/"raw" tab. What am I missing?

Comment: I like to use https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#Handlers for debugging this kind of thing. You can do something like `$ua->add_handler(request_prepare => sub { my($request, $ua, $h) = @_; p $request })` with Data::Printer and `use Data::Printer { class => { expand => 'all' }}`

Comment: Also are you sure there are any cookies? Or did you prepare the `lwp_cookies.dat` file to contain some?

Comment: @simbabque, when I use Postman tool to do the same requests I there's ASP.NET_SessionId cookie returned.

Comment: Maybe the server looks at the useragent string? Postman is a browser extension, right? Could be the server gives you a session cookie with Postman because it thinks you're a web browser, but not when you identify as _Perl LWP something_. Is that cookie required? Cookies are not exactly typical for REST APIs.

Comment: It's not required, but there's an anomaly that occurs in web interface of the application I'm using API for after I run my Perl script, which does not occur if I use Postman (yes, it's a Chrome plugin). I'm investigating why this happens and if I can modify my script to avoid the issue (I did report it to application devs, but there's no answer yet). The only differences I see are this cookie stuff, and some headers: Connection: "keep-alive" vs "TE, close", presence of TE in my script's headers, and some other ones, I assume should not be the issue (UA, Origin).

Comment: Sounds like a very localized problem though. I doubt we can find a simple answer. It's more like speculating.

Comment: you know, I found the problem -- has nothing to do with what my script is sending (I was not doing _exactly_ the same in Postman, it turned out). bit I really appreciate you trying to help! it's still strange that the code above doesn't work as I hoped for, I'll try the Handlers later. but it's not urgent anymore. thanks!!!

Comment: If the server doesn't send cookies back, it wouldn't put any in the cookie jar. And if the jar is empty, it wouldn't send cookies. Good luck figuring the rest out. :)